# Unable to run stored procedure on Azure Database for MySQL flexible server

Tags: mysql, database, azure, server

I am trying to create an run a stored procedure from my Azure Database for MySQL flexible server.

I have created the procedure, but when trying to run it with the call function I keep receiving the error:

> Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation   0.000 sec

Below you find the create statement of my procedure:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`<username`@`<servername>` PROCEDURE `<procedurename>`()
BEGIN

SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';
SET sql_mode = "";
 

SET @datum= CONCAT(year(now()),'-', LPAD(month(now()),2,'0'),'-','01');
SET @instantie='I000';
```

I found this help site from Microsoft but the solutions are not working:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/how-to-troubleshoot-common-errors#error-1227-42000-at-line-101-access-denied-you-need-at-least-one-of-the-super-privileges-for-this-operation-operation-failed-with-exitcode-1

I tried to give the useraccount permissions using:

```sql
GRANT CREATE ROUTINE ON mydb.* TO '<username>'@'<hostname>';
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE mydb.myproc TO '<username>'@'<hostname>';
```

Also changed the procedure without the DEFINER clause, but no luck.

Does anybody have seen this problem before and can help me fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: Please add the full create statement for your proc to your question.

Comment: @user1191247, I have added the create statement. thank you in advance!

Comment: I suspect it is your `SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';` which is triggering the error. Try setting it for the SESSION, instead of GLOBAL. Also, check [this note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/concepts-limitations#:~:text=LOAD%20DATA%20INFILE%20is%20supported%2C%20but%20the%20%5BLOCAL%5D%20parameter%20must%20be%20specified%20and%20directed%20to%20a%20UNC%20path%20(Azure%20storage%20mounted%20through%20SMB).) about having to use a UNC path